# Hot to make multiple element both on the left side and right side on html email?

Tags: html, css, html-email

It should support for `html email`, so I can't use `justify-content` and `align-items`.

I try to use `position: absolute` for `<img />`, but It's not working on html email ?

Hot do I make the Twitter icon on the left side and on the same line with 1 2 3 for `html email` ?

[image]

```
    <div
      class="footer-container"
      style="
      position: relative;
      background: pink;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;"
    >
      <!-- position is not working on html email -->
      <div
        class="image-container"
        style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 24px"
      >
        <img 
          src="https://www.citypng.com/public/uploads/preview/-516139511470ymv2hndq6.png"
          alt="test"
          width="94"
        />
      </div>
      <div
        class="centered"
        style="padding-top: 40px; padding-bottom: 40px; padding-right: 30px; text-align:right;"
      >
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a>3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for email templates, it is acceptable and correct to use a table for designing purposes! Centering within a table shouldn't be hard.

Comment: To find out what HTML/CSS is supported in emails, have a look at https://www.caniemail.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find <table /> how to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In email-templates you have limited support and as such sue techniques that are outdated or would not be semantically correct for normal HTML files.

In this case, you should use a table for layout purposes. You can shrink the table cells to their minimum content by using: `style="width: 0; white-space: nowrap;"`

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://www.citypng.com/public/uploads/preview/-516139511470ymv2hndq6.png" alt="test" width="94">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 0; white-space: nowrap;">
      <a>1</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 0; white-space: nowrap;">
      <a>2</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 0; white-space: nowrap;">
      <a>3</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

People forget that HTML email Table can be treated as a "grid" layout by using `colspan` (and `rowspan` as well). Usually a grid of **6 columns** fits best for most of the cases. Knowing you have such a grid, the top row can be constructed as such `colspan`s, and by using `text-align`:

```html
<style>
  td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
</style>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px;border-spacing: 0;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9TPY.png" alt="logo" style="display: block; vertical-align: middle; border: 0;" width="57" height="48">
      </td>
      <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right;">
        <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center; background: gold;"><br><br>6<br><br><br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">3</td>
      <td colspan="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">2</td>
      <td colspan="2">2</td>
      <td colspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center; background: #567; color:#fff;">5</td>
      <td colspan="1" style="text-align: center; background: #456; color:#fff;">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```